# How can I switch the order of a commit I rebased on to to the top of my stack of commits?

Tags: git, rebase

On my local branch, I had the following commits: `A->B->C->D` in that order. I rebased on top of `X`, and had to fix some conflicts, and now I have `X->A->B->C->D` on my local branch. I actually want it to be `A->B->C->D->X` so I did a `git rebase -i origin` and moved `X` to after `D`, but it's essentially making me fix the same conflicts I fixed before in reverse order, I think.

Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you continue with your current approach, there may be no avoiding the merge conflicts as X is played on top of the local branch.  However, you could also start with the local branch and then cherry pick the X commit:

```
# from local
git cherry-pick X
```